# insert into database fails at error code 1048

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
   <?=form_open('forums/register');?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_name">Username : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_name" disabled="disabled" value="<?=$_POST['username']?>"/></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_email">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_email" disabled="disabled" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_password">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="register_password" disabled="disabled" value="<?=$_POST['password']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return true;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('forums/index.php');return true;"></td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?=form_close()?>
```

This is my confirmation firm before the user information is saved into mysql table. But i have got this error I have no idea why, because it works with password and activation key but username and email address are all null's.

```
Column 'name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `membertb` (`name`, `email`, `pass`, `activation`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', '034db1787db6b3d72365507fcb2d1ca0')
```

and member data is read as follows

```
$member_data=array
        (
            'name'=> $p['register_name'],
            'email'=> $p['register_email'],
            'pass'=> md5($p['register_password']),
            'activation' => md5(uniqid(rand(),true))
        );
```

This initialization works fine as in my latest resolved problem about this.
Thank you for any helpful corrections ..

Answer (score 0):

Your register_name field is disabled in your HTML form. So it isn't sent to server. So $p['register_name'] is null, and I guess your 'name' field is NOT NULL.

Try using readonly instead of disabled in your HTML form.